# VIM: How to yank text in quotes on current line in ex mode?

Tags: vim

Lets say cursor is standing on line #10:

> foo bar "fizz" buzz

first character.

How can I yank `fizz` using ex mode (to do the same as `f"yi"` would do)?

Bonus points for ability to specify register.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can execute any normal mode command via `:normal` (add `!` to ignore any mappings; a good practice when writing plugins).

```
:normal! f"yi"
```

For special keys, enclose the command in `:execute`, as in:

```
:execute "normal! aText\<Esc>"
```